# How to append a null value to the beginning of a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How to append a null value to the beginning of a list?

**input**:

```
t=[10,12,15,16]
```

**Output**:

```
t=['null',10,12,15,16]
```

Comment: `['null'] + t`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
t.insert(0, None) # to add a None value
t.insert(0, 'null') # to add the word 'null' as a string
```

You can add an element to 0th index as above.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import deque

t = [10, 12, 15, 16]
d_t = deque(t)
d_t.appendleft('null')
```

out:

```
deque(['null', 10, 12, 15, 16])
```

> Deques are a generalization of stacks and queues (the name is
>   pronounced “deck” and is short for “double- ended queue”). Deques
>   support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either
>   side of the deque with approximately the same **O(1)** performance in
>   either direction. Though list objects support similar operations, they
>   are optimized for fast fixed-length operations and incur **O(n)** memory
>   movement costs for **pop(0)** and **insert(0, v)** operations which change
>   both the size and position of the underlying data representation.